# Creating a multidimensional array in scala

Tags: json, scala

I am parsing a json object like this:

```
val product_array:Option[Any] = scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull(products_json)

var product_array2 = Array()

product_array match {
case Some(p) => {
for {
  (id, desc) <- p.asInstanceOf[Map[String,Map[String,Any]]]
  (propName, propValue) <- desc
}  product_array2(id) ++ Array(propName->propValue.toString)
}
case None => test = "No products in shopping cart"
}
```

The problem is that I am trying to create a multidimensional array with this line:

```
product_array2(id) ++ Array(propName->propValue.toString)
```

But it doesn't work. How can I create a multidimensional array in the for loop?

Hopefully I can clarify:

In PHP it would be this:

```
product_array2[id][propName]=propValue;
```

Comment: Please be more clear what the intended outcome is. You want a multidimensional array, fine. But what is stored in which dimension? For example `product_array2(id)` does not make sense, because `id` is a String. My guess is you want to convert `id` to an integer and use that as the outer array dimension. But it is not clear from you current formulation.

Comment: PHP's `Array` is not what anyone else would recognize as an array. It's what's generally called a _dictionary_ or a _map_, and it is called a `Map` in Scala.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the structure, the answer of @lpaul7 will tell you how. If you want to update the structure, you either need to deal with the nested immutable Map, or convert the result indeed into a mutable structure (what you tried to do with the Array).

This gets all a bit nasty:

```
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSON._

val json = """{"id": {"age": 33}}"""

val im = parseFull(json) match {
  case Some(m: Map[_, _]) => 
    m.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]].collect {
      case (key, value: Map[_, _]) => (key, value.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]])
    }
  case _ => Map.empty[String, Map[String, Any]]
}
```

Query:

```
im("id")("age")
```

Immutable update:

```
val updated = im + ("id" -> (im.getOrElse("id", Map.empty) + ("age" -> 44)))
```

Mutable structure (using mutable maps both for the outer and inner structure):

```
import collection.{breakOut, mutable}

val mut: mutable.Map[String, mutable.Map[String, Any]] = 
   im.map { case (key, inner) => key -> mutable.Map(inner.toSeq: _*)} (breakOut)
```

Mutable update:

```
mut("id")("age") = 55
```

---

In other words, you will really want a [noise-free Scala JSON solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065897/noise-free-json-processing-with-scala), such as the [Lift's json](https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json/), [sjson](https://github.com/debasishg/sjson/wiki), or [Jerkson](https://github.com/codahale/jerkson) libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it easily:

```
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSON._

val products_json = """{"p...67890"}}"""

val product_array = 
  parseFull(products_json).get.asInstanceOf[Map[String,Map[String,Any]]]

println(product_array("product1Id")("product_name"))
```