# How to get instance of 2D array in scala any type

Tags: scala

My source is a JSON and we have a function which checks for a particular datatype(string or float or int) with case statements and if matches converts that into Byte array and returns back. Now how to get an instance of 2D array from Any data type or how to convert Any type to 2D array. For 1D array i just gave jsonNode.asInstanceOf[java.util.ArrayList[java.lang.String]] for 2D thought of adding one more parameter but asInstanceOf accepts only one parameter.

```
def validateDataTypes(jsonvalue: Any, dataType: String): Array[Byte] = {
  case "int8array2d" => {
    try {
      val p = jsonNode.asInstanceOf[?]
    } catch { }
  }
}
```

So how to convert Any type to 2D array?

Comment: what are you matching on ? this code is weird !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266036/creating-a-multidimensional-array-in-scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2D array type is `Array[Array[Int]]`:

```
jsonValue.asInstanceOf[Array[Array[Int]]]
```